# Can't click custom added UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I've got this transparent Navigation bar, and I can add a custom icon (code below). However it does not seem to respond to clicks, anyone have any idea why this could be caused?

I'm adding this inside a UIViewController which is inside a UINavigationController.

```
var button: UIButton = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "customBack"), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    button.targetForAction("doAction:", withSender: button)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

    var leftItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    leftItem.customView = button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.action = "doAction:"

    self.navigationController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```

I know I shouldn't be adding back items myself but in this exact case it is needed. The icon is added on the fly not before loading the view or w/e.

Comment: check whether the action method is defined as func doAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) { } and add a printf inside . Maybe you have to hide the default back button by self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

Comment: I had a breakpoint inside, that'd do fine but I found out already what was wrong in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always just after posting I find out:

I was using

```
button.targetForAction("doAction:", withSender: button)
```

Whilst I should be doing:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "doAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 1):

To try it...

```
var ysBackButton:UIButton = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kNavBtnSize, kNavBtnSize))
ysBackButton.setImage(UIImage(named: kBack), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
ysBackButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("backButtonAction"), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
var leftBarButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: ysBackButton)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
```